# Selection screen value request for multiple files in a select option

Tags: abap

I would like the user to be able to select multiple local files and for the filenames to be populated on a selection screen in a single select option. There is code which I found online:

```
REPORT zsritest3.

TABLES: file_table.

DATA: lt_file_names TYPE FILETABLE,
      lwa_file_name TYPE FILE_TABLE,
      lv_subrc TYPE i.


SELECT-OPTIONS: so_file FOR file_table NO INTERVALS.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR so_file-low.

CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog
  EXPORTING
*    WINDOW_TITLE            =
*    DEFAULT_EXTENSION       =
*    DEFAULT_FILENAME        =
*    FILE_FILTER             =
    INITIAL_DIRECTORY       = 'C:Temp'
    MULTISELECTION          = 'X'
  CHANGING
    file_table              = lt_file_names[]
    rc                      = lv_subrc
*    USER_ACTION             =
  EXCEPTIONS
    FILE_OPEN_DIALOG_FAILED = 1
    CNTL_ERROR              = 2
    ERROR_NO_GUI            = 3
    others                  = 4.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
*            WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
ENDIF.

so_file-sign = 'I'.
so_file-option = 'EQ'.

LOOP AT lt_file_names INTO lwa_file_name.
  so_file-low = lwa_file_name.
  APPEND so_file.
ENDLOOP.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  LOOP AT so_file.
    WRITE: / so_file-low.
  ENDLOOP.
```

From https://answers.sap.com/questions/1131589/selecting-multiple-files-for-f4-help.html?childToView=1131776

I tried running that exact code but when I tried the F4 help and selected multiple files using the CTRL key, the select option had two entries but they were both the first file I selected.

Does anyone know what's wrong with the code in that link and how to fix it?

Comment: The program looks correct. I also ran it and the result is correct, showing all the multiple files I have selected.
Please check after the selection with F4 all the files needed, clicking on the icon right to the select-options field, that all file names were transfered to the  "Select Single Values" list.

Comment: That's weird because I'm doing the same thing and after clicking open in the file dialog I see the first file displayed as I expect. Then when I click on the extension button I only see the first file in both lines and it's uppercase in the first line and lowercase in the second line. I don't see the second file selected at all. I'm on ABAP 7.4 if that makes a difference?

Comment: It's actually the second file selected that I see in both lines, not the first.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use select-options for multiple files selection, because it can cause problems with transferring the data from the input field iteself. It is enough to have normal file type parameters field.

The method `cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog` with parameter **`multiselection = abap_true`** (same as 'X') returns the internal table of interest.

```
REPORT report_name.

DATA: lt_files TYPE filetable,
      lv_rc    TYPE i.

PARAMETERS: p_fileml TYPE file.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_fileml.
  CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog
    EXPORTING
      initial_directory       = 'C:\Temp'
      multiselection          = 'X'
    CHANGING
      file_table              = lt_files
      rc                      = lv_rc
    EXCEPTIONS
      file_open_dialog_failed = 1
      cntl_error              = 2
      error_no_gui            = 3
      OTHERS                  = 4.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
      p_fileml = 'File(s) are selected'.
  ELSE.
    WRITE : / 'Error on cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog'.
  ENDIF.
```

```
START-OF-SELECTION.

  LOOP AT lt_files ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_file>).
    WRITE: / <fs_file>-filename.
  ENDLOOP.
```

`lt_files` internal table contains all the selected file names.